# longest common subword incorrect result

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've been trying to write a program that calculates the longest common continuous sequence (or subword) two strings have in common.The code works without any syntactical errors but everytime I get gibberish random results like 237743 etc, hope someone can figure out where i went wrong.
for example,
If I enter the first word as 'stack' and second word as 'stackoverflow' ,it should give an output of 5(common word=stack, length 5) but it gives me '2752053'

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getlcw(char arr1[],char arr2[])
{
    u=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    v=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    if(u==0||v==0)
    {   cout<<"fail";
        return 0;
    }
    int lcw[u+1][v+1]; \\1 extra row and column to indicate word has ended , no chance for subword
    int maxlcw=0;
    for(int i=0;i<u+1;++i) \\intialise last row and col to 0
    {
        lcw[i][v+1]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<v+1;++i)
    {
        lcw[u+1][i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=u;i>=0;--i)
    {
        for(int j=v;j>=0;--j)
        {
            if(arr1[j]==arr2[i])
                lcw[i][j]=1+(lcw[i+1][j+1]);
            else
                lcw[i][j]=0;
            if(lcw[i][j]>maxlcw)
                maxlcw=lcw[i][j];
        }
    }
    return maxlcw;
    }

int main()
{   int x,y;
    cout<<"enter size of word 1\n";
    cin>>x;
    char arr1[x];
    cout<<"enter size of word 2\n";
    cin>>y;
    char arr2[y];
    cout<<"word 1\n";
    for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
    {
        cin>>arr1[i];
    }
    cout<<"word 2\n";
    for(int j=0;j<y;++j)
    {
        cin>>arr2[j];
    }
    int ans=getlcw(arr1,arr2);
    cout<<ans;
    cin>>x;

}
```

Here's the link from where I got the idea for the algo  -

https://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/topics/dp-classics.php

Comment: you need to adjust your notion of "everything seems fine" and learn how to use a debugger

Comment: Add an example with expected and produced result. Try debugging!

Comment: did so.Sorry I am new to this place.

Comment: Generally, check your array indexing... if you have an array of length `x`, valid indices are in the range `[0, x-1]`. If you try to access index `[x]`, it will be out of range - you do this a lot in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it two ways, Review it:

Top down approach :

```
int getlcw(char arr1[],char arr2[])
{
    u=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    v=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    if(u==0||v==0)
    {   cout<<"fail";
        return 0;
    }
    int lcsw[u+1][v+1]; \\1 extra row and column to indicate word has ended , no chance for subword
    int maxlcw=0;


    for(int i=0; i<u+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<v+1; j++)
        {
            if(i == j)              lcsw[i][j] = 0;
            if(arr1[i]!= arr2[j])   lcsw[i][j] = 0;
            else                    
            {
                                    lcsw[i][j] = 1+lcsw[i-1][j-1];
                                    maxlcw= max(maxlcw, lcsw[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return maxlcw;
}
```

Bottom-up As you're trying :

```
int getlcw(char arr1[],char arr2[])
{
    u=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    v=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    if(u==0||v==0)
    {   cout<<"fail";
        return 0;
    }
    int lcsw[u+1][v+1]; \\1 extra row and column to indicate word has ended , no chance for subword
    int maxlcw=0;

    for(int i=u;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=v;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(i == j)              lcsw[i][j] = 0;
            if(arr1[i]!= arr2[j])   lcsw[i][j] = 0;
            else                    
            {
                                    lcsw[i][j] = 1+lcsw[i+1][j+1];
                                    maxlcw= max(maxlcw, lcsw[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```